# Eclipse - How to know if 32bit or 64bit installation

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have Linux Mint (Ubuntu based) installed. I just installed Eclipse using `sudo apt-get install eclipse` and it installed successfully. My system is 64 bit; but I don't know if installed Eclipse is 64bit or 32bit? Is there any way to know this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to install from apt-get packages. Go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and pick one which best suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following command to know the bit version:

```
$ file /path/to/eclipse
eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (
```

Comment: What can be /path/to/eclipse/ ? I've no clue!

Answer (score 1):

When you do it like this, you do not need to know.  `apt-get` will choose one usable with your OpenJDK installation.

Personally I've found that the Eclipse distribution coming with Ubuntu rapidly gets old compared to the latest downloads from eclipse.org, and that the Eclipse internal plugin system does not work well with apt-get.

I would recommend that unless you are satisfied with the Eclipse version coming with Ubuntu as-is, you should simply download what you need from eclipse.org and manually invoke the launcher.  If you are in doubt whether to get the 32-bit or 64-bit version, then look at the Help->About Eclipse and look for isntallation details.  You can then tell from the JVM information.